# Count rows in table with certain value in other table

Tags: mysql

I need a quick way to find the Number of items in a table. The items are linked to an other table. Table 1 is products and table 2 is orders.

Orders contains a paid status (1 or 0).

Orders table example:

```
id paid
1  0
2  1
```

Products table example:

```
id orderid type
1  1       5
2  1       5
3  1       3
4  2       5
5  2       5
6  2       3
```

Products contains a id (orderid) that refers to the order and a type. So i need the number of products where type = 5 and paid = 1 in the orders table.

What is the best and fastest way to archieve this?

So I need all the paid products with type 5. The result should be '2'.

Comment: We need the db schema, sample data and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use join like this,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.id = products.orderid 
WHERE type = 5 AND paid = 1
```

Comment: your answer is the same as Sharlike

Comment: didnt noticed that earlier .i was typing mine. not exactly the same in a sense, but yet the process is same. so.should i remove mine ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a join statement. Making some assumptions about your schema, the following should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.`id`) FROM `products_table` p
LEFT JOIN `orders_table` o ON p.`orderid` = o.`id`
WHERE o.`paid` = 1
AND p.`type` = 5
```